# Creation of RegEx(s) for System Uptime Ranges in Days

Tags: regex

I am receiving output from remote hosts into a proprietary InfoSec appliance that can check the output against a regular expression.  The appliance documentation does not specify a language or engine it uses for RegEx matching.  The appliance runs on Linux, if that helps at all...

I am receiving system uptime stats from remote hosts in the following format:

```
n days, n hours, n minutes
```

Examples:

```
23 days, 23 hours, 52 minutes  
0 days, 2 hours, 13 minutes  
9 days, 12 hours, 0 minutes
```

I'm trying to build a policy around ranged days of uptime, so I need a regex that will look at the beginning of the string and match if the output is 7 days or less, another RegEx that will match 7 to 14 days, and another regex that will match 14 days or more.

Comment: When you say "7 days or less", would something like `7 days, 10 hours, 5 minutes` match?   Or do you want that to fail to match since it's over 7 days exactly?

Comment: Fail, because it's over 7.  So 0-6, 7-13, and 14+.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To match less than 7 days:

```
^[0-6] days, \d+ hours, \d+ minutes
```

To match 7 to 14 days:

```
^([7-9]|1[0-3]) days, \d+ hours, \d+ minutes
```

To match 14 days or more:

```
^(1[4-9]|[2-9]\d|\d{3,}) days, \d+ hours, \d+ minutes
```

However, for simplicity, those patterns are not inclusive of the exact end number of days.  For instance, `7 days, 0 hours, 0 minutes` will be matched by the second pattern, not the first one.  That's why I called the first pattern "less than 7 days" rather than "7 days or less".

Similarly, `14 days, 0 hours, 0 minutes` will be matched by the third pattern rather than the second one. If you need it to to work the other way on those two edge cases, that would complicate the patterns considerably.

Comment: From what I've tested so far, this looks to be exactly what I was requesting!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

### Brief

The easiest method is simply to split the string on `,` and then use `^\d+` to match the digits and do your tests thereafter. The more complicated solution is the regex below, which captures the number of days into separate groups. Groups represent the following values if they're set:

1. 7 days or less

   - I'm assuming here that this means `00:00:00` to `06:23:59`
2. 7 - 14 days

   - I'm assuming here that this means `07:00:00` to `13:23:59`
3. 14 days or more

   - I'm assuming here that this means anything outside the range of the above two options

---

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/Mk3BqZ/1)

```
^(?:([0-6])|([7-9]|1[0-3])|(\d+)) days, (\d+) hours, (\d+) minutes$
```

---

### Explanation

- `^` Assert position at the start of the line
- (?:([0-6])|([7-9]|1[0-3])|(\d+))` Match either of the following options

  - `([0-6])` Capture a number between 0-6 into capture group 1
  - `([7-9]|1[0-3])` Capture a number between 7-9 or 10-13 into capture group 2
  - `(\d+)` Capture any number into capture group 3 (catches what isn't caught by previous options, thus 14-∞)
- `days,` Match this literally
- `(\d+)` Capture the number of hours into capture group 4
- `hours,` Match this literally
- `(\d+)` Capture the number of minutes into capture group 5
- `minutes` Match this literally
- `$` Assert position at the end of the line

Comment: This is an interesting concept, but I needed three separate RegEx(s) for this conditional based policy to work.  Thank you for your time.